# compiler error assigning a new pair<T> object to an existing pair<T> object

Tags: c++11, boost, c++builder-xe7

The following code produces an error in C++Builder XE7, using the 32-bit compiler:

```
    #include <utility>
    #include <boost/any.hpp>

    std::pair< int, boost::any > y;
    void test()
    {
      y = std::pair< int, boost::any >( 1, 2 ); // error!
    }
```

The error is:

```
"Could not find a match for 'operator std::pair<int,boost::any>::=(std::pair<int,boost::any>)'"
```

I don't get it.  There is nothing inherently wrong with this code, and it compiles just fine in (much) older compilers.  Now here are the interesting bits:

1) The 64-bit compiler compiles the code without error

2) If I change the pair's second type from 'boost::any' to a built-in type, such as 'int', the code compiles without error

As a work-around, I was able to do this:

```
    #include <utility>
    #include <boost/any.hpp>

    std::pair< int, boost::any > y;
    void test()
    {
      std::pair< int, boost::any > temp = std::pair< int, boost::any >( 1, 2 );
      y = temp;
    }
```

It's less efficient, but it gets me around the compiler error.

Until recently, I had been using antiquated C++ compilers (C++Builder 5/6), so I have not kept up-to-date with the C++ standards and the changes for C++11.  Therefore, I might be unaware of a language change that makes this code invalid.  So, can someone please tell me if this compiler error is a result of a language change, or is it a compiler bug?

Thanks,

Dennis

Comment: I'll take "the 32-bit compiler is hopeless" for $10, Alex

Comment: If you really have to build 32bit executables then as a workaround you can use TVariant instead of boost::any

Comment: I'm going to go with [compiler bug](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbcec21108a05907).

Comment: Your first example calls `operator=(&&)`, the second `pair(&&)` then `operator=(const&)`.  Add a `move` to the assign in the second example, do you get the same error?

Comment: Do you mean like this?:

std::pair< int, boost::any > y = std::move( std::pair< int, boost::any >( 1, 2 ) );

No, no error.  The same error occurs, however, with this:

  std::pair< int, boost::any > z;
  z = std::move( std::pair< int, boost::any >( 1, 2 ) );

(Could not find an operator=())

Comment: Simpler call also fails:  y = std::move( temp );

Comment: `std::move()` is part of C++11, which the 32bit compiler does not support yet (it is in work).

Comment: Remy, I'm using std::move() in some code, and it appears to work (I've verified that my code does what I expect it to).  So something must be there.  Maybe the current implementation of std::move() that comes with XE7 is a temporary work-around to allow code to compile?